# Что должно быть в коде приложения для размещения его как платного в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

После того как приложение написано, что и где надо прописать в его код для размещения в Google Play как платное? Имеется ввиду защита, привязка к аккаунту.

Может, где-то уже все расписано давно, но не могу найти. Пишу в Android Studio.

Comment: Это настраивается в Google Play Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нигде ничего в код встраивать не надо для того, чтобы выложить приложение как платное.

Платность/бесплатность приложения настраивается при его выкладывании в маркет. При этом сменить позже это нельзя. (Точно нельзя бесплатное сделать платным, а вот платное временно бесплатным, вроде, можно. Но это не точно.)

Установить платность/бесплатность приложения можно в `Google Play Console` -> `Настройки страницы приложения` -> `Цены и распространение`. См. скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Я выложил бесплатное приложение, часть контента в нем платная, но оплата производится через сторонний сервер. Хотел чтобы оплата дополн.контента проходила через PlayMarket. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Получается надо заново собрать проект, создать еще ключ, подписать и выложить как новое приложение?

Comment: А как настроить продажу только дополнительного контента?

Comment: @kaaa, у вас 2 варианта. 1 - да, выпустить приложение с полным функционалом отдельное и сделать его платным. Юзеров направлять его покупать и им пользоваться. Это неудобно всем и уже не модно. 2 - сделать встроенную покупку/подписку для активации платного функционала. Для этого гуглите InAppPurchase. В документации довольно неплохо всё описано.

Comment: Все понял, буду копать в сторону InAppPurchase